# How to send a timestamp input to a SP in typescript using mssql package?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, typescript, npm

I am using mssql npm package to interact with SQL server. I have a situation where when I fetch the variable(type being TIMESTAMP in sql server) in a SP, it is returned as byte array. Now I need to send into another SP as parameter whose type is TIMESTAMP in sql server.(FYI : this functionality is a migration work from dotnet to nodejs).

When I get the variable(type: DATESTAMP) from SQL server, the output is as below.

invoiceDetail.UpdTS =
{
type: 'Buffer',
data: [
0,  0,   0,   0,
44, 88, 104, 217
]
}

now I want to send this as variable into another SP.

I tries like below.

.input("UpdTS", sql.####, invoiceDetail.UpdTS)    => #### -> dont know what should be the type.

I tried to convert it into a hexstring and tried sending it as

(invoiceDetail.UpdTS converted to a class then ran data to a function to get the hex string)

.input("UpdTS", sql.Varchar, '000000002c5868d9')   => getting error here

Comment: `timestamp` is a deprecated synonym for `rowversion`, which is a `binary(8)` value. It has *nothing* to do with date and times.

Comment: use `sql.Binary` and a byte array

Answer (score 0):

You will be wanting to use the `sql.Binary` or `sql.VarBinary` input types, as per the [`mssql` DataTypes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#data-types) documentation. e.g.:

```js
const sql = require('mssql')

const sqlConfig = {
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PWD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    server: process.env.DB_SERVER,
    port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT ?? '1433'),
    pool: {
        max: 10,
        min: 0,
        idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
    },
    options: {
        encrypt: false,
        trustServerCertificate: true
    }
}

const foo = async () => {
    try {
        const ID = 1
        const pool = await sql.connect(sqlConfig)
        const result = await pool.request()
            .input('ID', sql.Int, ID)
            .query('select ID, UpdTS from dbo.InvoiceDetail where ID = @ID')
        console.log('Result:')
        console.dir(result)

        const UpdTS_Buffer = result.recordset[0].UpdTS
        console.log('UpdTS_Buffer:')
        console.dir(UpdTS_Buffer)

        await pool.request()
            .input('OldID', sql.Int, ID)
            .input('NewID', sql.Int, ID+1)
            .input('UpdTS', sql.Binary(8), UpdTS_Buffer)
            .execute('dbo.InvoiceDetailUpdate')

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Something broke:`, err)
    }
}
foo().then(() => process.exit(0))
```

Which outputs:

```
Result:
{
  recordsets: [ [ [Object] ] ],
  recordset: [ { ID: 1, UpdTS: [Buffer [Uint8Array]] } ],
  output: {},
  rowsAffected: [ 1 ]
}
UpdTS_Buffer:
Buffer(8) [Uint8Array] [
  0, 0, 0,   0,
  0, 0, 7, 209
]
```